# Bootstrapping A Mean: What is the significance (if any) of a converging mean for n iterations?

Tags: mean, bootstrap

I have a stochastic signal, and I'm taking its mean in the canonical way and comparing that with a bootstrapped mean:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['count'] = gaussian_data

# slow sample but transparent and simple to implement
# iterative mean is more accurate
# sampling is done with replacement
def bootstrap_mean(n):
    mu = 0
    for i in range(1, n):
        update = df['count'].sample(n=100, replace=True).mean() 
        mu += (update - mu) / i

    return mu    

print "bootstrapped mean:%f" % bootstrap_mean(10001)    
print "canoncial    mean:%f" % df['count'].mean() 


# bootstrapped mean:171.311726 
# canoncial    mean:171.297387
```

OK looks good for 10k iterations...what about trying over several n:

```py
x = np.arange(1e3, 1e4, 100)
mu_n = map(bootstrap_mean, x)
plt.plot(x, mu_n)
```

[image: plot of bootstrapped mean over n iterations]

I thought the mean over the iterations would converge cleaner and that the meaning would be, the samples are covering the distribution well.

How should I interpret this plot ?

EDIT:
Using the range of values after n=3000: 
(approximate range)
Can I say that I have a mean with $\mu \pm 0.15$

Comment: Despite the large code segment, this seems to me thoroughly on-topic as an essentially statistical question.

Comment: I think I need to add an inner loop and run each sample m times. Perhaps aiming for a p value this way will be more intuitive.

Comment: Nobody has anything to add....?? I thought this was a standard industry application of boot strapping.

Comment: Not everybody read python so maybe describe in words what the code is doing?